# HTML/CSS - Input [Text] How to disable the browser from offering suggestings in the Dropdown?

Tags: html, css, input

I'm building an autosuggest search, like apple's spotlight... and want to disable the browser from offering text suggestions under the input box. I can't remember if that's an html or css setting and can't find it.

Anyone remember?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The attribute:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

is, I think, what you're looking for.

Comment: that's it... Strange, CODA didn't have that as a hint

Comment: It’s a non-standard attribute until HTML5 (see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute), so it will make your code invalid under other HTML doctypes. Sounds like it’s worth it in this context, although you could switch to the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) to get valid code without having to change anything else.

Comment: I know Stackoverflow is so old-skool, but thanks for that regardless

Answer (score 17):

html attribute:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Comment: I think it's autocomplete="off"

Answer (score 9):

To disable auto-completion of input fields, use the HTML attribute `autocomplete` with a value set to `off`.

`<... autocomplete="off" .../>`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work in modern browsers. Use:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

If you need pleaceholder add css:

```
[contenteditable="true"][placeholder]:after {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #abb4cd;
}
[contenteditable="true"][placeholder]:not(:empty):after {
    display: none;
}
```